# Automatically give grants to particular users PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, permissions

Every time when someone creates a table I have to give grants on select, insert, and so on to particular users. Are there any solutions to make it automatically?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html

Comment: the version of postgresql  is 9.4 ;(

Comment: That works in 9.4 as well. But: Postgres 9.4 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  anyway - you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Grant to a role. Then grant that role to the users that need it.

Answer (score 0):

There is `alter default privileges`, but this does not accept a wild card for the users it will apply to (i.e. the creating roles).  You have to list every possible creating user, which is quite a drag.